# Remove a program from windows 10 startup permanently

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot

How can I remove a (portable) program from windows 10 startup permanently? (It has an option at first run to include it in windows startup.)

I can disable startup items from its corresponding tab in `Task Manager`, but I can't delete an item from there permanently.

Also note that in Windows 10, the `msconfig` startup just refer to the task manager again. The `msconfig` in older versions of windows show the location of startup item (eg the registry address) but this info is not shown in task manager. Also, I prefer to find an easy way to do it without searching through the registry.

Comment: [Remove invalid entries from Task Manager Startup tab](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/task-manager-startup-tab-entries-remove-invalid/)

Comment: @Win32Guy Thanks, yes, registry editing was always an option, but it is time consuming and dangerous. I'm looking for a better/easier way

Comment: Many of us would utilize [Autoruns](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns) to disable or remove Windows startup items.

Comment: @Run5k Yes it is a very good tool. Thanks for mentioning it!

Comment: To remove the entry from the registry is not so dangerous if you are able to follow the instructions. Most tweaks out there do not refer to system critical settings and you can always make a backup first. It's like editing any configuration file. There is much to much awe out there for the Windows registry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several best free tools for this purpose:

- [Autoruns](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns): a good light weight utility (under 1 MB) which enable you to disable or delete startup items. "It has the most comprehensive knowledge of auto-starting locations, shows you what programs are configured to run during system bootup, and when you start various built-in Windows apps in your startup folder, Run, RunOnce, and other Registry keys. Autoruns reports Explorer shell extensions, toolbars, browser helper objects, Winlogon notifications, auto-start Services, and much more."
- [CCleaner](http://www.ccleaner.com/): a general tool that do many cleanings (like as clean up the registry, cookies, other undesirable elements), and it also allows you to delete entries from the startup file.
- [Startup Delayer](https://www.r2.com.au/page/products/show/startup-delayer/): remove applications from your startup, also it has the ability to delay the launching of startup apps (to get better performance just after you start the windows). "Startup Delayer gives you the power to optimize Startup Process by delaying applications from starting up as soon as you log into your computer. By delaying the applications during start up, your computer becomes usable a lot faster. Startup Delayer will then start launching your delayed applications when your computer is more idle."
- MsConfig in windows prior to Windows 10 (typing "msconfig" in the run dialogue Win+R) provide a way to remove unwanted apps from startup.

Comment: autoruns worked when other "conventional" windows options didn't